# TFS 2013, mapping new states to the Stories board

Tags: tfs

It might not be possible for user stories, but I'm trying to show the new state that I created in the stories board.

We are using the Stories backlog board and under tfs (even through the board by clicking on the items) we can set the items to the new state.

All the info that I've found is about tasks or bugs by exporting the wit file using witadmin but I can't see any way to do the same with user stories.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to export the process configuration file for your Team Project using witadmin.exe

[Import and export process configuration [witadmin]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500413(v=vs.120).aspx)

```
witadmin exportprocessconfig /collection:http://TFS2013:8080/tfs/defaultcollection /p:MyProject /f:C:\Temp\processconfiguration.xml
```

Add in your new state in the requirements category, for example, an "In Progress" state

```
<RequirementBacklog category="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" pluralName="Backlog items" singularName="Backlog item">
    <States>
      <State value="New" type="Proposed" />
      <State value="Approved" type="Proposed" />
      <State value="Committed" type="InProgress" />
      <State value="In Progress" type="InProgress" />
      <State value="Done" type="Complete" />
    </States>
```

Then import again

```
witadmin importprocessconfig /collection:http://TFS2013:8080/tfs/defaultcollection /p:MyProject /f:C:\Temp\processconfiguration.xml
```

Finally, go into your kanban board settings and add a column for the new state.

Some more detail [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500412(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much!! I already tried exporting it but as I didn't find any userstory work item there (I found bugs, tasks and other stuff) I didn't know where I had to change that to make it work, knowing that is under RequirementBacklog makes it easier to understand know. Thanks again.