# Add custom state to TFS backboard page

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have added a custom state called "Ready to test" to my PBI work item type. My users want this state to appear on the TFS backboard page in addition to the existing "New", "Approved", "Committed", "Done" columns.

What I need is  "New", "Approved", "Committed", "Ready to test", "Done" columns.  Can anyone provide the code I need to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question here:
[TFS 2013, mapping new states to the Stories board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35317376/tfs-2013-mapping-new-states-to-the-stories-board/35322736#35322736)

So to add Ready to Test to the Kanban board, your processconfig will look like this:

```
<RequirementBacklog category="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" pluralName="Backlog items" singularName="Backlog item">
<States>
  <State value="New" type="Proposed" />
  <State value="Approved" type="Proposed" />
  <State value="Committed" type="InProgress" />
  <State value="Ready to Test" type="InProgress" />
  <State value="Done" type="Complete" />
</States>
```

Remember to add the new state to your Bug Work Item too as it is also a Requirement by default in the Scrum template.